# How to get all non deleted messages from one user 

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5, performance, query-performance

I have two tables one for messages called default_messages and the other for recipients called default_recipient. This is how SQL for those table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sender_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply_to_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thread_root_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

And this is the DATA for this table:

```
INSERT INTO `default_messages` (`id`, `subject`, `message`, `sender_user_id`, `reply_to_message_id`, `thread_root_message_id`, `date`, `deleted`) VALUES
(1, 'asdasdadasdasdasdasd', 'sdasdasdad', 1, 0, 0, '2012-05-11 09:29:00', 1),
(2, 'sadasdasd', 'asdasd', 2, 0, 0, '2012-05-11 09:44:23', 0),
(3, 'Re: asdasdadasdasdasdasd', 'asdadadadadadad', 2, 1, 0, '2012-05-11 09:44:41', 1),
(4, 'Re: sadasdasd', 'asdadad respuesta', 1, 2, 0, '2012-05-11 09:46:22', 1);
```

Now for the second table this is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_recipient` (
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recipient_read_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the DATA is this one:

```
INSERT INTO `default_recipient` (`message_id`, `user_id`, `read`, `recipient_read_date`, `deleted`) VALUES
 (1, 2, 1, NULL, 0),
 (2, 1, 1, NULL, 1),
 (3, 1, 1, NULL, 1),
 (4, 2, 1, NULL, 1);
```

Now I have this query for get all messages for user_id=x where deleted columns in both tables default_recipient and default_messages is not equal to 1 but it's not working because I get two results instead of one when user_id at table recipient or sender_user_id at table messages takes value equal 2:

```
SELECT p.*, rcp.*, msg.*, msg.id as message_id FROM default_messages msg 
        LEFT JOIN default_recipient rcp ON (msg.id = rcp.message_id)
        LEFT JOIN default_profiles p ON (p.user_id = msg.sender_user_id)
        WHERE msg.sender_user_id = 2 OR rcp.user_id = 2
        AND msg.deleted = 0 AND rcp.deleted = 0
        ORDER BY msg.date DESC
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** The right question here was: how to get all messages for one user "X" let says where rcp.deleted = 0 **OR** msg.deleted = 0

Comment: why don't you use group by at the end of the query?

Comment: @jcho360 group as GROUP BY msg.sender_id? Meaning GROUP BY id because in both tables have to be the same? That is your suggestion?

Comment: @jcho360 that wouldn't solve anything...

Comment: I'm not getting the error, sorry, I thought that you are receiving 2 times every columns

Comment: @jcho360 he gets two rows but expects only one

Comment: @JNK so Yes, it could be done with a group by (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c76/16).

Comment: @jcho360 except it's still not giving the expected results

Comment: @JNK ohh THAT's is another problem, did you check with him the design of the DB?, prob start from there could be a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions

### SUGGESTION #1 : Refactor the Query

```
SELECT
    p.*, rcp.*, msg.*, msg.id as message_id 
FROM
    (
        SELECT id FROM default_messages
        WHERE sender_user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
        ORDER BY date DESC
    ) msgkey
    LEFT JOIN default_messages msg ON (msgkey.id = msg.id)
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM default_recipient
        WHERE user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
    ) rcp ON (msgkey.id = rcp.message_id) 
    LEFT JOIN default_profiles p ON (msg.sender_user_id = p.user_id) 
;
```

### SUGGESTION #2 : Index the tables to support the subqueries

```
ALTER TABLE default_messages ADD INDEX (sender_user_id,deleted,date,id);
ALTER TABLE default_recipient ADD INDEX (user_id,deleted);
```

As an example, I loaded the data from your question and indexed the two tables

```
mysql> use reynierpm
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists default_messages;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> drop table if exists default_recipient;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_messages` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `subject` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `sender_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `reply_to_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `thread_root_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    ->   `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_recipient` (
    ->   `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `read` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `recipient_read_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE default_messages ADD INDEX (sender_user_id,deleted,date,id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE default_recipient ADD INDEX (user_id,deleted);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `default_messages` (`id`, `subject`, `message`, `sender_user_id`, `reply_to_message_id`, `thread_root_message_id`, `date`, `deleted`) VALUES

    -> (1, 'asdasdadasdasdasdasd', 'sdasdasdad', 1, 0, 0, '2012-05-11 09:29:00', 1),
    -> (2, 'sadasdasd', 'asdasd', 2, 0, 0, '2012-05-11 09:44:23', 0),
    -> (3, 'Re: asdasdadasdasdasdasd', 'asdadadadadadad', 2, 1, 0, '2012-05-11 09:44:41', 1),
    -> (4, 'Re: sadasdasd', 'asdadad respuesta', 1, 2, 0, '2012-05-11 09:46:22', 1);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `default_recipient` (`message_id`, `user_id`, `read`, `recipient_read_date`, `deleted`) VALUES
    ->  (1, 2, 1, NULL, 0),
    ->  (2, 1, 1, NULL, 1),
    ->  (3, 1, 1, NULL, 1),
    ->  (4, 2, 1, NULL, 1);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->     rcp.*, msg.*, msg.id as message_id
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT id FROM default_messages
    ->     WHERE sender_user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
    ->     ORDER BY date DESC
    -> ) msgkey
    -> LEFT JOIN default_messages msg ON (msgkey.id = msg.id)
    -> LEFT JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT * FROM default_recipient
    ->     WHERE user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
    -> ) rcp ON (msgkey.id = rcp.message_id)
    -> \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            message_id: NULL
               user_id: NULL
                  read: NULL
   recipient_read_date: NULL
               deleted: NULL
                    id: 2
               subject: sadasdasd
               message: asdasd
        sender_user_id: 2
   reply_to_message_id: 0
thread_root_message_id: 0
                  date: 2012-05-11 09:44:23
               deleted: 0
            message_id: 2
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

I altered the query to test the join of the two tables:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     rcp.*, msg.*, msg.id as message_id
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->     SELECT id FROM default_messages
    ->     WHERE sender_user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
    ->     ORDER BY date DESC
    -> ) msgkey
    -> LEFT JOIN default_messages msg ON (msgkey.id = msg.id)
    -> LEFT JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT * FROM default_recipient
    ->     WHERE user_id = 2 AND deleted = 0
    -> ) rcp ON (msgkey.id = rcp.message_id)
    -> \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            message_id: NULL
               user_id: NULL
                  read: NULL
   recipient_read_date: NULL
               deleted: NULL
                    id: 2
               subject: sadasdasd
               message: asdasd
        sender_user_id: 2
   reply_to_message_id: 0
thread_root_message_id: 0
                  date: 2012-05-11 09:44:23
               deleted: 0
            message_id: 2
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

I get one row. As the two tables grow, the indexes will help the refactored query run fast.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 3):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Your condition is parsed and executed as:

```
    WHERE (msg.sender_user_id = 2) 
       OR ( rcp.user_id = 2
        AND msg.deleted = 0 
        AND rcp.deleted = 0
          )
```

Perhaps you mean to write:

```
    WHERE (msg.sender_user_id = 2 OR rcp.user_id = 2)
      AND msg.deleted = 0 
      AND rcp.deleted = 0
```

Comment: that one doesn't return anything

Comment: @ReynierPM Then you need to give us some sample data and expected output.  We are guessing here.  You probably have a dupe on one of your join keys but its impossible to tell without more data.

Comment: Results are here http://pastebin.com/Vd6zS9d3

Comment: @ReynierPM put that in your QUESTION.  And are those actual or expected?  Give us sample data as well plz.

Comment: @ReynierPM: I will delete this answer. Please do as JNK advised. Post your results and what is your desired result in the question (edit it). It woudl be good if you described what you want your query to return (say: "all deleted messages of user with id=2 and all its recipients")

Comment: @ypercube don't delete, I think I know the issue.  See my answer, it depends on yours :)

Comment: @ypercube Ok, my question was bad at first but now and thanks to ypercupe and JNK and jcho360 it works.

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on your pasted data, you have two rows that match your criteria.  `Msg_Id` values are `2` and `3`.

Your `WHERE` filter is very loose because of the issues that ypercube pointed out.

Currently you will match ANY rows where `msg.sender_id = 2`.

You get no rows back when you apply a proper filter because both those messages have `rcp.deleted = 1` set.

**So, you need to clarify what you want exactly.**

Do you want to see non-deleted messages?  If so, there are no matches.

Do you want to see messages from user `2`?  If so, this is the the right result.

Do you want to only filter by `msg.deleted=0`?  If so, remove the `rcp.deleted` filter and I think you will get what you want if you properly group your filters.

Comment: clarify at post edit

Comment: @ReynierPM Ypercube's answer is correct.  You are getting 0 rows because they are both deleted in one of the tables.

Comment: I want to filter by msg.deleted = 0 and rcp.deleted = 0 and msg.sender_user_id = X and rcp.user_id = X

Comment: @ReynierPM yes.  If you look at your data all messages for user 2 are deleted in the recipient table.

Comment: hmmm deleted for me is when value takes 1 and not you're wrong see first row at table recipient where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2

Comment: @ReynierPM The userid for that is 1...you aren't filtering on recipient user, you are filtering on msg.user

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3438/discussion-between-jnk-and-reynierpm)

Comment: hmmm I'm wrong or I see user_id = 2 and deleted = 0 adn message_id = 1 at table default_recipient?

Comment: come to chat please